# date_format() in PHP not returning the formatted date

Tags: php, wordpress, date, datetime

The `date_format` function is not returning the formatted value of the variable but instead the current date only

I have tried different date variables and formats but to no avail. This is done in WordPress environment.

....

```
 <span class="some-css-class">
  <?php
   $eventDate = new DateTime(the_field('date_event'));
   //'event_date is the name of the date time field created for the post
   echo date_format($eventDate,'M'); 
  ?>
  </span>
```

....

I have tried different variables and number formats. Searched for WordPress environment specific solutions but none works.
The result shows today's date being formatted instead of the given date.

The result shows the date of the event in non-formatted form and today's date in formatted form.

Comment: Your code is `the_field('date_event')` and then in the comment you mentioning `event_date` -> the words are in different order. Do you have the variable name written correctly?

Comment: You start with OO `new DateTime()` and then revert to Proceedural `date_format()` why not `$eventDate->format('M');` Just for consistance like :)

Comment: You dont actually tell us what the problems are! ___Debugging 1o1___ `echo the_field('date_event');`  to check what it is actually returning, Oh and show that to us as well

Comment: you can use date function to format given date. DATE('M',the_field('date_event'));

Answer (score 1):

> The result shows today's date being formatted instead of the given date.

That’s because you are *not* giving *any* date to the DateTime constructor here - so it defaults to today.

```
$eventDate = new DateTime(the_field('date_event'));
```

`the_field` *outputs* the value directly. You want to pass the value as a parameter into the DateTime constructor, so you need to use the function that *returns* the value instead of outputting it directly - `get_field`.